# Broken button in Finder?

Tags: macos, big-sur

After upgrading to MacOS Big Sur(Version 11.0.1), an arrow that appears right next to the search field in Finder appears to be broken. Clicking on it does not do anything. Could this be a potential bug?

[image]

Comment: It could be a bug.  It's supposed to be an 'overflow' for buttons that don't fit the width of the Finder window.

Comment: On a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** that icon has a _circle with three dots in it_ to the left of the _down arrow_ and is called an **Action** menu. Have you tried removing it and adding it back? **Finder** > **View** > **Customize Toolbar…**, or _right-click_ on the **Toolbar** and select  **Customize Toolbar…**, then drag it off of the **Toolbar**, and drag it back on to the **Toolbar** from the _sheet_.  -- Never mind, I see the **Action** menu at the left side of the cropped screen shot. You could still see if it can be dragged off.

Comment: @user3439894 Action option is already there in the toolbar which is the first icon on left end of the screenshot. I tried remove it using Customize Toolbar option but now it's unclear what it was as the options available are only the valid ones.

Comment: As I already said "Never mind, I see the **Action** menu at the left side of the cropped screen shot." That said, does it really matter what it was as it was non functioning anyway? You can see what's available and add anything additional that you'd like.

Comment: I can't duplicate that issue on Big Sur but I have an idea. What if you Customize Toolbar and add a space just to the left of the search field. That might push that icon to the left and reveal what it is trying to do.